# Inserting the address of a constant in inline assembly code

Tags: c, inline-assembly, mov

I want to translate this function:

```
iowrite32(mem1, value1);
```

into assembly code.

mem1 is defined as:

```
int * mem1;
```

in order to use ioremap.

I've written this code:

```
asm volatile(
    "mov    %[whr],%[wht]"
    : [whr] "=r" (mem1)
    : [wht] "r" (value)
);
```

Then I've realized I don't want to move value to mem1, but to the ADDRESS stored in mem1.
How do I write it in assembly?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the `m` constraint

```
asm volatile(
    "mov    %[wht], %[whr];"
    : [whr] "=m" (*mem1)                                                   
    : [wht] "r" (value)
);
```